# Can I use conditionally rendering method in a JSX tag in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, render

Just like the title, can I use conditionally rendering in a JSX tag in React?

What I want to inprement:
There is a button to switch on/off using useState, and if you press the button,
you put a prop into a JSX tag to send to the child component.

Here is my codes:

```
const [swithOn, setSwithOn] = useState(true)

<Custum swithOn ? style={{opacity : 0}} : null />
```

However, it doesn't work.
So, to make this work, should I do it like this?

```
{swithOn ? <Custum style={{opacity : 0}} /> : <Custum />}
```

This works as expected, but because there are two JSX tags "Custum" in the statement, my codes will get quite messy...

Is there any other better way here?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the style itself according to the condition:

```js
const { useState } = React

const Custum = ({ children, ...props }) => <div {...props}>{children}</div>

const Demo = () => {
  const [swithOn, setSwithOn] = useState(true)
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Custum style={swithOn ? { opacity: 0 } : { color: 'red' }}>
        Entire Style
      </Custum>
      
      <Custum style={{ color: 'red', opacity: swithOn ? 0 : undefined }}> 
        Style Prop Value
      </Custum>
      
      <Custum style={{ color: 'red', ...(swithOn ? { opacity: 0 } : null) }}> 
        Style Prop
      </Custum>
      
      <button onClick={() => setSwithOn(!swithOn)}>toggle</button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<Demo />)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Wow  thank you so much for showing me several ways to tackle on this! I bet this will definitely come in handy for other people like me as well! Btw, what does '...swichOn' do in the last statement?

Comment: The `...(swithOn ? { opacity: 0 } : null)` is select `{ opacity: 0 }` or `null`, and then spread it. Spreading `{ ...null }` - > `{}` and `{ ...{ opacity: 0 } }` ->  `{ opacity: 0 }`.